# How to Perform Regular Expression in JTextArea of Swing

Tags: java, regex, jtextarea, replaceall

I want to Replace all Matched words with given Regular Expression.I wrote code for that.But,It just replace it but that particular action was not performed.When I select the Regular Expression then I click on Replace All,It will replace with particular action,not replace with the given String/Character.
For example My input is "\n",Matched String/Character replace with New line Action,not replace new Line Character.Please check it and help me.Thank you.
My Code:

```
public class RegularExp extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JTextArea text;
int i=0;
UndoManager undoManager = new UndoManager();
public RegularExp() {
    initComponents();
    text = new JTextArea();
    replace.setEnabled(false);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    replace = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    fileMenu.setText("File");

    open.setText("Open");
    open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(open);

    replace.setText("Replace");
    replace.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            replaceActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(replace);

    jMenuBar1.add(fileMenu);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void replaceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    JDialog replace_dialog=new JDialog(RegularExp.this);
    replace_dialog.setTitle("Replace");
    JLabel find_label=new JLabel("Find what");
    final JTextField find_tf=new JTextField(10);
    JLabel replace_label=new JLabel("Replace With");
    final JTextField replace_tf=new JTextField(10);
    final JCheckBox regx=new JCheckBox("Regular Expression");
    JButton replaceAll=new JButton("Replace All");
    replace_dialog.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    replace_dialog.add(find_label, c);
    c.gridx++;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;
    replace_dialog.add(find_tf, c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    replace_dialog.add(replace_label, c);
    c.gridx++;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;
    replace_dialog.add(replace_tf, c);
    c.gridx++;
    c.gridx++;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    replace_dialog.add(replaceAll, c);
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy++;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    replace_dialog.add(regx, c);
    replace_dialog.setSize(400,400);
    replace_dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    replace_dialog.pack();
    replace_dialog.setVisible(true);
    replaceAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(regx.isSelected()){
                int caret_pos=text.getCaretPosition();
                text.setText(text.getText().replaceAll(find_tf.getText(),"\\"+ replace_tf.getText()));
                text.setCaretPosition(caret_pos);
            }    
            else {
                int caret_pos=text.getCaretPosition();
                text.setText(text.getText().replaceAll(find_tf.getText(), replace_tf.getText()));
                text.setCaretPosition(caret_pos);
            }
        }
    });
}                                       

private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    final JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal=  jc.showOpenDialog(RegularExp.this);
    String title;
    File file=null;
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    file = jc.getSelectedFile();
    if (jc.getSelectedFile()!= null) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegularExp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String t = str.toString();
        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true);
        title=file.getName();
        text.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
        internalFrame.add(text);
        i+=1;
        internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
        JScrollPane scrollpane=new JScrollPane(text);
        internalFrame.setTitle(title);
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.add(scrollpane);
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
        text.setText(t);
        text.setCaretPosition(0);
        replace.setEnabled(true);
    }
}                                    

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegularExp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegularExp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegularExp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegularExp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RegularExp().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem open;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem replace;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is: in one of the cases you should use the function `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`.

Note that both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` functions replaces all the occurrences. The only difference between them is that `replaceAll()` uses regex, while `replace()` don't.

So you should use the following code:

```
replaceAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int caret_pos = text.getCaretPosition();
        if(regx.isSelected()){
            text.setText(text.getText().replaceAll(
                    find_tf.getText(), replace_tf.getText()));
        }
        else{
            text.setText(text.getText().replace(
                    find_tf.getText(), replace_tf.getText()));
        }
        text.setCaretPosition(Math.min(caret_pos,text.getText().length()));
    }
});
```

---

According to your comments, your question does not have to do with regular expressions. You simply want to handle special characters like `\n` and `\t` differently in two situations. I'll let the above explanation to the ones that really want to use regular expression. Also, I'll add below, the answer to your specific situation.

**UPDATED ANSWER TO WORK IN BOTH SCENARIOS THAT YOU'VE DESCRIBED IN COMMENTS:**

```
replaceAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int caret_pos = text.getCaretPosition();
        if(regx.isSelected()){
            text.setText(text.getText().replace(
                    find_tf.getText().replace("\\n","\n").replace("\\t","\t"),
                    replace_tf.getText().replace("\\n","\n").replace("\\t","\t")));
        }
        else{
            text.setText(text.getText().replace(
                    find_tf.getText(),
                    replace_tf.getText()));
        }
        text.setCaretPosition(Math.min(caret_pos,text.getText().length()));
    }
});
```

This code deals with `\n` and `\t`. If you want to deal with other special characters you just have to add other replaces. For example: if you want to deal with `\r` you need the following code:

```
text.setText(text.getText().replace(
        find_tf.getText().replace("\\n","\n").replace("\\t","\t").replace("\\r","\r"),
        replace_tf.getText().replace("\\n","\n").replace("\\t","\t").replace("\\r","\r")));
```

You can have a list of all JAVA escape sequences here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

- `\t`    Insert a tab in the text at this point.
- `\b`    Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
- `\n`    Insert a newline in the text at this point.
- `\r`    Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
- `\f`    Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
- `\'`    Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
- `\"`    Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
- `\\`    Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

Comment: The above code also Just replace the given String with Find string.I Explain my requirement with an example:Input Text is:  SN1*84*9*CA~HL*95*2*I~HL*98*2*I~CTT*98 , Find What is:~ and Replace is:\n.Case 1:when I select the Regular Expression then click on Select All Button.The Output should be in Four lines .Example Output:SN1*84*9*CA
HL*95*2*I
HL*98*2*I
CTT*98   case 2:when I click on Replace All Button without select the Regular Expression,The output should be one line.The Example Output is:SN1*84*9*CA\nHL*95*2*I\nHL*98*2*I\nCTT*98.

Comment: In the above The Second case is working fine.Please check the First case.Thank you for reply.

Comment: I understand now what you want. I updated the above answer to your needs.

Comment: Find What and Replace are not Fixed.In the above I just show an sample example.When I give Replace as \t,In this case not added tab space when ~ occur.The above Edited program reverse is not working \n with ~ then the output should back to original.

Comment: My Requirement is When I select Regular Expression then click on Select All.The replace string function will happen and reverse also.For example Find what:~ and Replace:\n(~ is replaced with new line function).Find what:* and Replace:\t(* is replaced with tab space(Four white spaces)).Reverse means Find What:\t Replace:* (\t(tab space) is replaced with *).It gives original text.I think you can understand my requirement.Please check it once.For reference check with TextPad Editor(Search->Replace).

Comment: I've updated the answer again. Now it works for both the scenarios you've described.